# How to skip failed sub-playbook and continue to next

Tags: ansible

Using playbook structure as,

```
---
- import_playbook : A.yml
- import_playbook : B.yml
- import_playbook : C.yml
- import_playbook : D.yml
- import_playbook : E.yml
- import_playbook : F.yml
- import_playbook : G.yml
```

If B is having some issues and failed, entire run fails. How do we skip the failed playbook(B) and start playbook C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way how to gracefully exit a play is [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html#meta-execute-ansible-actions) module

```
- meta: end_play
```

Put into the [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks) the tasks that may have the issues and end the play in the *rescue* section if any of the tasks fails. To proceed to the next play clear errors with `- meta: clear_host_errors`.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - block:
      - command: /bin/false
    rescue:
      - debug:
          msg: Command failed. End of play.
      - meta: clear_host_errors
      - meta: end_play

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Next play started.
```

Comment: It works perfect if we have around 2-3 playbooks in a loop. But what if we have more than 10, we can't just change it for all playbook every time. Is there any kind of scenario we can do directly after import_playbook and make use of handler conditions.

Comment: IMHO this is the only way (and I searched properly). Let me know if you find an alternative. But, I don't understand why you should "`change it for all playbook every time`"? What's wrong with the block-rescue-meta construct? I'd recommend to use it routinely.

Comment: Next option worth to review might be [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).

Comment: Never-mind, tested and worked perfectly fine, thanks man